# Dinamic html page for videos of DB

Tags: javascript, php, html

first time asking, so apologies for some format errors.

I'm creating a site, and wanted to be able to post some videos which would be in the main page and when clicked would open a page, where it would be displayed.

The main page is done and I do retrieve the paths from the database, with php to an array, to use as:

```
  <video width="100%">
     <source src="<?=$rows[$counter]['path']?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">                               
  </video>
```

My question is how do i create a basic HTML file with the id or path of the file, so when i click on a video, it opens that page to display the video in question.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what your above code is? What does `"<?=$rows[$counter]['path']?>.mp4"` equate to? Note that you're probably actually looking for `"<? echo $rows[$counter]['path']; ?>.mp4"`, but your logic is sound in that regard.

Comment: For the video itself yes, but for the page to display it not so much.
What's missing is the page, so when i click the link/video, it redirects me to that page

Comment: @ObsidianAge What's the difference between the OP's row echo compared to yours? Other than that you're using short open tag, which is disabled as default, since a few years back.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [anchor tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) and set the target="_blank"

It's not clear what you're asking but you could try

```
<a href="<?=$rows[$counter]['path']?>.mp4" target="_blank">     
    <video width="100%">
        <source src="<?=$rows[$counter]['path']?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">                               
    </video> 
</a>
```

Comment: While I wouldn't really consider this an 'answer', I'd also recommend **against** this, as `target=_blank` opens you up to a [**phishing attack**](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) unless it is accompanied with `rel=noopener`.

Comment: He's asking to open his own content in another window/tab. He's not opening some other webpage.

Comment: Can u elaborate that please? i would use target="_blanck" and it would open in a new tab right?
but how about the page? cause my objective was to create only one page, and the content/video would change with the Id or path

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you have in your src attribute. But you could try putting that URI in to an anchor tags href. <a href="<?=$rows[$counter]['path']?>.mp4" traget="_blank">My Video</a> Unless you wanted to be able to see the video on your page and clicking on it would open into another page. Then wrap the video tag in that anchor tag.